# Domain SSL is not working, what should I do?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a VM to host my website, it has a temporary IP that is working correctly. Now I need to put ssl to increase site security. I verified that it is possible to enable "Custom Domain" and obtain a certification with Let's Script, I added my domain and it generated a DNS record.

[image: DNS record]

I am trying to use this IP but it does not work, just the IP of my VM, the IP of my VM does not work HTTPS, I figured the IP of the custom domain would work, how do I enable ssl?

Google Cloud

Comment: If you created the certificate for the domain, the IP wont be secure. Also when you say “I am trying to use this IP” which IP do you meN the VMs temporary IP?

Comment: What kind of web server do you use ? nginx ? or apache? The ssl should be Offloading by your web server. And do you setup firewall rule for 443 port ?

Comment: I used the image button in the toolbar and pasted the image url, so that the image is visible inline.